# Get average of each nested array in dynamic object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm iterating this JSON using a `for` loop:

```
var movieObj = {
    "cat": {
        "moveName": "Breath",
        "rating": [4, 5, 4, 3]
    },
    "cat1": {
        "moveName": "shallow",
        "rating": [5, 5, 5, 5, 4]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to improve this code?

```
var sum;

Array.prototype.getSum = function (ele) {
    sum = ele.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    });
    return sum / ele.length
}

for (var key in movieObj) {
    var b = movieObj[key];

    if (Array.prototype.getSum(b['rating']) < 5) {
        console.log(b['moveName']);
    }
}
```

Comment: The title of the question indicates the use of opinion, specifically "what is the best way to write the blow code", the rest of the question is fine. Is there some way to could change the title? Please see this webpage on how to ask a good question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should ensure that each `key` is a properly defined member of `movieObj`, not part of the prototype:

```
for (var key in movieObj) {
    if (movieObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instead of declaring `getSum` on `Array`, you can use the builtin [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```
var sum = function(previous, current) {
    return previous + current;
};

var ratings = movieObj[key].rating;

if (ratings.reduce(sum) / ratings.length < 5) {
    // ...
}
```

Finally, your `console.log` statement can use direct property access, instead of square bracket notation.  I believe `moveName` is a typo, and should in fact be `movieName`, but correct me if I'm wrong there:

```
console.log(movieObj[key].movieName);
```

Putting it all together gives:

```
var sum = function(previous, current) {
    return previous + current;
};

for (var key in movieObj) {
    if (movieObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var ratings = movieObj[key].rating;

        if (ratings.reduce(sum) / ratings.length < 5) {
            console.log(movieObj[key].movieName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Global Variables

In current code, the variables `movieObj`, `sum`, etc. are global. Global variables are *bad* and can create problems when the variable names collide with other developer's namespaces. This will be very difficult to debug in moderate-size projects.

See [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice)

To make the variables and methods *private*, use [Module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

### Naming Conventions

Use the descriptive variable names such that it'll give the idea of what it may contain, what is the purpose of it.

Example, the variable `b` in the `for...in` can be renamed to `val` as it is the value of a key or `movie` as the object stores the information of a movie.

Read [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) second chapter "Meaningful Names".

### Overriding the prototype method

**Always** check if a particular method exists on the prototype. If it does not exists, then only add one. Also, regarding the name of method, I'll name the method as `sum` instead of `getSum`. Chances are, there will be method with same name and functionality in the future versions of ECMAScript and the code doesn't have to be changed.

```
if (!Array.prototype.sum) {
    Array.prototype.sum = function () {
        // Do something
    };
}
```

### `for...in` vs `Object.keys()` + `forEach`

[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over object is slower<sup>[Benchmark](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/t33407w7/)</sup>. Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the list of all keys in that object and use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on that array to iterate over it.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    // ...
});
```

### `this` inside method defined on prototype

`this` inside the method on prototype refers to the variable on which the method is called. Example, when calling `array.push`, `this` inside the `push()` will refer to the `array` on which the method is called. So, there is no need to pass the array as parameter to the method.

```
Array.prototype.sum = function () {
    console.log(this);
    // Use `this` to refer to array
};
```

### Bracket notation vs Dot notation

When the keys are known and are static and does not contain special characters, use the dot notation to access the value of that key in the object. Dot notation is faster and clear to read.

Instead of `obj['moveName']`, use `obj.moveName`.

See [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

### Typo

In the object, the keys for movie name has typo. It should be `movieName`.

### ECMAScript 2015

If the target environment support latest version of JavaScript, use the features provided by it.

### Complete code:

```js
if (!Array.prototype.sum) {
    Array.prototype.sum = function () {
        var sum = this.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
        return sum / this.length;
    };
}

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var movieObj = {
        cat: {
            movieName: 'Breath',
            rating: [4, 5, 4, 3]
        },
        cat1: {
            movieName: 'shallow',
            rating: [5, 5, 5, 5, 4]
        }
    };

    Object.keys(movieObj).forEach(function (key) {
        var movie = movieObj[key];

        if (movie.rating.sum() < 5) {
            console.log(movie.movieName);
        }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Array.prototype.getSum()` is awkward and against the beautiful principles of JS's prototypical structure. Since it will reside in the prototype of all arrays to be defined it shall be invoked by the array itself. No need to pass an argument.

In test code i would agree with Tushar's correction but in production you can not and should not simply extend the `Array.prototype` like that. You should use `Object.defineProperty()` tool and make this extension a non enumerable property.

I also believe that the function could have been named more involvedly like `Array.prototype.average()` since you are not getting sum but the average. Also you might simplify `Array.prototype.average()` and the rest of the code as follows;

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"average",{ value: function(){
                                                           return this.reduce((p,c) => p += c/this.length,0);
                                                         }
                                                });
var movieObj = {
    "cat": {
        "moveName": "Breath",
        "rating": [4, 5, 4, 3]
    },
    "cat1": {
        "moveName": "shallow",
        "rating": [5, 5, 5, 5, 4]
    }
};

Object.keys(movieObj).forEach(k => movieObj[k].rating.average() < 5 && console.log(movieObj[k].moveName));
```